# Setting and checking cookies for bypassing mobile view

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm trying to use javascript cookies to bypass the mobile view. I've got this script on the mobile site:

```
<script>
function setCookie(nomo,nomovalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = nomo+"="+nomovalue+"; "+expires;
}
</script>
<p>Click to View<br /><a onClick="setCookie('nomo', 'nomovalue', '1')" href="../home.asp">Desktop site</a></p>
```

And this script on the non-mobile site:

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!-- 
    function checkCookie() {
        var nomocheck = getCookie("nomo");
        if (nomocheck != "") && (screen.width <= 699) {
            document.location = "mobile/mobile_home.asp";
            }
    }

    }

//--></script>
```

Nothing is happening, but I don't know what's wrong. Little help.

Comment: nomo is a function ? If not why are you calling onclick nomo. If yes why are you passing it to secooikie fn. The second fn it should be nomocheck!=''

Comment: I've edited the code but still nothing.